# Использования свойства

Tags: c#, property

Моя цель чтобы переменная hp фильтровалось и было больше нуля, и меньше 101, что я неправильно делаю ?

```
class Monster
    {
        public Monster()
        {
            hp = 0; name = "unknown";
        }
        public Monster(string name, int hp)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.hp = hp;
        }
       public int Hp
        {
            get { return hp; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0 && value <= 100) hp = value;
                else hp = 0;
            }
        }
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}",name,Hp);
        }
        int hp;
        string name;
    }
    class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Monster monster = new Monster("a", -1);
            monster.Print();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ты не используешь свое свойство при вводе значения

Comment: Меняете в конструкторе переменную `this.hp` вместо свойства `this.Hp`.

Comment: спасибо, решил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Monster(string name, int hp)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.Hp = hp; // Свойство, не поле
}

public int Hp
{
  get { return hp; }
  set { hp = value < 0 ? 0 : value > 100 ? 100 : value; }
}
```